# is it possible to revert a order from "invoiced" to "not invoiced" programmatically?

Tags: invoice

Once i click the submit invoice button, a invoice will be created and i saw there are something has been changed in database, is it possible to revert a order into "not invoiced", so i can recreate the invoice again?

And i tested even if i delete a invoice in database, but i still can't to create a invoice for that order

--update--

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Varien_Profiler::enable();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
//Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
//$invoiceId = $_GET['invoiceid'];          //put your invoice id - the autoincrement one not the long one.
//Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId)->delete();

  $orderId = 100000049; // this is an example 
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
  $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
  var_dump($invoices);
  foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
        $invoice->delete();
  }
```

Comment: When loading by the increment id `100000049` then you can use the function `loadByIncrementId` on the order object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. This is code snippet as per your requirement.

```
<?php 
  $orderId = 101; // this is an example 
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
  $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
  foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
     $invoice->delete();
  }
?>
```

Comment: this is not work for me.

Comment: at which place you put your code?

Comment: magento root directory

Comment: i've post the script

Comment: I can't see the script

Comment: i posted the script

Comment: make sure the order id is available in database

Comment: the order id i use is 100000049 that exists (i saw it in backend)

Comment: no your order id is only '49' just try 49 and run

Comment: same, the invoice still exist after i run the script

Comment: i think the order_id in database is different from the display from backend admin, i run the script and deleted the invoice, but i still can't re-invoice the order, there is no button i can click

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are just deleting the invoice of the order but not the actual state of that order which is currently invoiced. To do that apart from deleting the invoice, you have to revert its state also.
Try this:

```
$orderId = YOUR_ORDER_ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->load($orderId);
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true)->save();
```

This will revert the order to new state, after that you can create new invoice for it.

Answer (score 1):

I also have encounter with the same issue, and unfortunately answers above did not work for me. So I ended up comparing all fields in `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_item` tables before and after invoicing. Now I use the following SQL snippet to "revert" invoice for order:

```
SET @order_id = YOUR_ORDER_ID_HERE; -- <<< Put your order ID here

DELETE FROM sales_flat_invoice where order_id = @order_id;

UPDATE sales_flat_order
SET
    state = 'new',
    status = 'pending',
    base_discount_invoiced = NULL,
    base_shipping_invoiced = NULL,
    base_subtotal_invoiced = NULL,
    base_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    base_total_invoiced = NULL,
    base_total_invoiced_cost = NULL,
    discount_invoiced = NULL,
    shipping_invoiced = NULL,
    subtotal_invoiced = NULL,
    tax_invoiced = NULL,
    total_invoiced = NULL,
    forced_shipment_with_invoice = NULL,
    hidden_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    base_hidden_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    surcharge_invoiced = NULL,
    base_surcharge_invoiced = NULL,
    base_linked_amount_invoiced = NULL,
    linked_amount_invoiced = NULL,
    base_total_paid = NULL,
    total_paid = NULL,
    customer_note_notify = 1,
    base_total_due = NULL,
    total_due = NULL
WHERE entity_id = @order_id;

UPDATE sales_flat_order_item
SET
    qty_invoiced = NULL,
    tax_invoiced = NULL,
    base_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    discount_invoiced = NULL,
    row_invoiced = 0,
    base_row_invoiced = 0,
    locked_do_invoice = NULL,
    hidden_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    base_hidden_tax_invoiced = NULL
WHERE order_id = @order_id;
```

If you really need Magento PHP code, you can "wrap" the commands above the following way:

```
// assume you've already removed records from sales_flat_invoice and now need to "clean up" the order
// also assume you keep order ID in $orderId
$writeConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$orderTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order');
$orderItemTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_item');

$query = "UPDATE $orderTableName " . <<<SQL_CODE
SET
    state = 'new',
    status = 'pending',
    base_discount_invoiced = NULL,
    base_shipping_invoiced = NULL,
    base_subtotal_invoiced = NULL,
    base_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    base_total_invoiced = NULL,
    base_total_invoiced_cost = NULL,
    discount_invoiced = NULL,
    shipping_invoiced = NULL,
    subtotal_invoiced = NULL,
    tax_invoiced = NULL,
    total_invoiced = NULL,
    forced_shipment_with_invoice = NULL,
    hidden_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    base_hidden_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    surcharge_invoiced = NULL,
    base_surcharge_invoiced = NULL,
    base_linked_amount_invoiced = NULL,
    linked_amount_invoiced = NULL,
    base_total_paid = NULL,
    total_paid = NULL,
    customer_note_notify = 1,
    base_total_due = NULL,
    total_due = NULL
WHERE entity_id =
SQL_CODE;
$query .= $orderId;
$writeConnection->query($query);

$query = "UPDATE $orderItemTableName " . <<<SQL_CODE
SET
    qty_invoiced = NULL,
    tax_invoiced = NULL,
    base_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    discount_invoiced = NULL,
    row_invoiced = 0,
    base_row_invoiced = 0,
    locked_do_invoice = NULL,
    hidden_tax_invoiced = NULL,
    base_hidden_tax_invoiced = NULL
WHERE order_id =
SQL_CODE;
$query .= $orderId;
$writeConnection->query($query);
```